# Search if my HTMLCollection contains certain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, contains, indexof

I have search function for properties that is allowing me to search for number of bedrooms, bathrooms, price (high and low) and I am trying to also get it to tell me if a customers search word, or words, is in the record. Like "River" or something.

I have been playing with .contains() and .indexOf() and but can not get either to work. Here are a few that I have tried;

```
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
var item = x[i];
if (item.getElementsByTagName("Bedrooms")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue >= filterBed
&& item.getElementsByTagName("BathsTotal")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue >= filterBath
&& item.getElementsByTagName("ListPrice")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue >= filterPrL
&& item.getElementsByTagName("ListPrice")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue <= filterPrH
&& item.getElementsByTagName("PublicRemarks").text().toLowerCase().contains(filterWord)
) {
```

and;

```
    && item.getElementsByTagName("PublicRemarks").indexOf(filterWord)
```

I have tested the key words are coming through and I have checked that they are in the records being searched.

Any help getting this working would be much appreciated.

Comment: getElementsByTagName will return an HTMLCollection which does not have a `text()` or `indexOf()` method... your console should have shown undefined?

Comment: ok. I have tried with and without the .text() as I am at a loss and have been trying everything I can think of. My console did show undefined.  The point of my article is that I have not got it working and would like help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, since you are using jQuery:

```
$(item).find("PublicRemarks").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterWord) > -1
```

`$()` will turn the `item` dom into a jquery object. then we find `PublicRemarks` tags within it, extract the text, make it lowercase, and look for filterword. If filter word is not found, `indexOf()` will return `-1`.

---

With just javascript, this could be done by looping through the collection. Could create a function to do this to reduce levels of complexity in your conditional... something like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2okcf4r/)

```
function collectionContains(collection, searchText) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        if( collection[i].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) > -1 ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `indexOf()` returns -1 if it could not find the word, so you should use `$(item).find("PublicRemarks").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterWord) > -1`

Comment: Is there a way to also make it check all of the sub nodes?

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean. Maybe post a new question and post your DOM and exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: @LeeGellie, actually by "check" I thought you meant checkboxes. Maybe you meant for this code to look into "sub nodes" (nested?) as well. The `.find()` will actually look at all text within all "PublicRemarks" tags (within the `item`) no matter how deeply nested.